# Writing and reading ADTF3 Files

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, adtf3

I am using [ADTF Libraries](https://github.com/cariad-tech/adtf_file) to write a structure data. I need to verify whether the data is being written properly. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I am assuming you are writing structured data to a .dat/.adtfdat file. In that case, you can always convert a .dat/.adtfdat file into a csv to verify. See [examples](https://github.com/cariad-tech/adtf_file/tree/master/src/examples) on how to do so.
2. If you have access to MATLAB, then the easiest way would be using a simple function in MATLAB : [adtffilereader](https://www.mathworks.com/help/driving/ref/adtffilereader.html)
3. Alternatively, there are these [tools](https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf_libraries/adtf-dat-gui-tools/v0/guides/intro_dattool_gui.html) that help in extracting data out of a dat file.

Comment: Hi LA_ thanks for the reply. I was using the examples to read the adtfdat file, but it reads only the header info. I would like to see the data written in the file. The matlab functions are not available to free users. Is  ADTF DAT Tool GUI available for evaluation?

Comment: ADTF DAT Tools are part of ADTF File Library. So, they are already available as explained here : https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf/v3/guides/tutorial_dat_tool_processor.html . You can always use a trial version of MATLAB if you want something quick. I think there is MATLAB Online as well, if you dont want to install anything